# Please tell me this stochastic process's name

Tags: stochastic-processes

Firstly, I'm not good at English, sorry. Please tell me this stochastic process's name $x_t=x_{t−1}−λ\operatorname{sgn}(x_{t−1})+ε$, where $ε$ is Gaussian noise and $λ>0.$

Comment: Why should it have a particular name in the first place? Where does it come from or where have you seen it? Looks to me like some sort of ARMA model.

Comment: On deep learning, I saw this stochastic process. We use lasso model, so loss function is added |ω|, that differentiated sgn(ω). It looks to me like AR model,too.

Comment: I want to proove this model($x_t$)  converges 0, so I want to know this process's name.

Comment: You don't need the name of something in order to study its convergence properties. And due to the answer user619894 gave below, I highly doubt it's converging to $0$ btw.

Comment: This process seems for me that is simple. So I think there is this process's name.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The continuum limit (the limit of short time steps) is
$$ \dot x =-\lambda \operatorname{sgn}(x)+\epsilon$$ which is a Smolochowski diffusion equation.

In fact, the force $F(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ comes from a potential field $F(x)=\lambda \nabla|x|$ So it admits a stationary Boltzmann solution $$P(x)=e^{-|x|\beta}$$ where $\beta$ is a function of $\lambda $ and $\sigma$.